# Overloaded operator has too many parameters, visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to declare an overload, non-friend, non-member ' - - operator in a header file:

```
 Quad operator-(const Quad &qu1, const Quad &qu2);
```

But I am getting:

```
 "error C2804: binary 'operator -' has too many parameters"
```

This code is right from the book and problem statement and I cannot seem to resolve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might need to show some of the surrounding code - that line works for me in VS2013 with a simple `Quad` class.

Comment: Just a guess...Are you sure that you have put this declaration outside the body of the Quad class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary operators in class definition scope must take only one argument.

```
Quad operator-(const Quad &quRight)
{
    Quad res;
    res.x = this->x - quRight.x;
    // all other components
    // ...
   return res;
}
```

Or you can move operator overloading outside of class.

Comment: The OP did say "non-member" in his question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that

Comment: You are probably right though, possibly a missing closing brace is causing it to be inside the class.

Comment: The problem is that I did not understand that non-member functions should be declared outside of a class... thanks very much for the clarification everyone.

Comment: @Serge please mark this answer as accepted. That way others with the same problem can see that it was the correct solution.